# Angular mat stepper delay for waiting informations

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component who call a service to retreive data.
Here is the part of that component:

```
getHardwareCheckInfosOne(serial){
    console.log(serial);
    this.hardwareCheckService.readOne(serial).subscribe((hardwareInfos: HardwareInfos[]) => {
    const arr = []
    arr.push(hardwareInfos);
    
    this.type = arr[0].type;
    this.payload_hex = arr[0].payload_hex;
    this.measure = arr[0].measure;
    this.Time = arr[0].Time;
    this.DevEUI = arr[0].DevEUI;
    this.IdCiterne = arr[0].IdCiterne;
    this.ShipTo = arr[0].ShipTo;
    this.Address = arr[0].Address;
    this.Signal = arr[0].Signal;
    this.serial_number = arr[0].serial_number;
    this.Battery = arr[0].Battery;
    this.brand = arr[0].brand;
    this.device_version = arr[0].device_version;
    this.connectivity = arr[0].connectivity;
    this.date_entry_stock = arr[0].date_entry_stock;
    this.date_install = arr[0].date_install;
    this.installer = arr[0].installer;
    this.status = arr[0].status;
    this.result = arr[0].result;
    this.Battery_OKO = arr[0].Battery_OKO;
    this.GSM_quality = arr[0].GSM_quality;
    this.radio_quality = arr[0].radio_quality;
    this.serial_OKO = arr[0].serial_OKO;

    console.log(this.DevEUI);

    this.TankDetailsService.getTechnician(this.installer).subscribe((Technician: Technician[]) => {
       this.NomTech = Technician[0].NomTech;
         });

    });
    
  }
```

The retreived data must shows in a step of my form. Here is the 2nd step of my form (the last step):

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="confirmFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="confirmFormGroup">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Hardware Check Report</ng-template>

          <div class="title m-0">Here is the serial for the device {{serial_number}}</div>

          <div class="mt-4" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px">
            <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="terms">
              etc etc etc. *
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>

          <div class="actions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
            <button color="primary" mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">PREVIOUS</button>
            
              FINISH
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </mat-step>
```

The problem is that data came after the step is initialize and I must go to previous and next to see that data. 
Is there exist an delay for the stepper for waiting data or maybe i'm not in the good way to do that? 
Thank you in advance for helping a Angular beginner.

**EDIT 1** 
Here is the first step of my form. When I click on the next button, the fonction getHardwareCheckInfosOne is initialize:

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="deviceInfos">
        <form [formGroup]="deviceInfos">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Device Informations</ng-template>

          <h2 class="title m-0">Device Informations</h2>
          <div class="subheading-1">Enter the device informations to test it.</div>

          <div class="mt-4" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px">
           <mat-form-field class="vex-flex-form-field" fxFlex="auto">
             <mat-label>Select device type</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="deviceType" (selectionChange)="setDeviceType($event)">
   <mat-option *ngFor='let option of deviceTypeOptions' [value]="option">
    {{option}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select> 
  </mat-form-field>

 <mat-form-field *ngIf= "deviceSelected === 'AIUT GSM'" fxFlex="auto" >
              <mat-label>Serial OKO</mat-label>
              <input formControlName="serialOKO"  matInput>
              <div *ngIf="deviceInfos.controls.serialOKO.hasError('invalidFormat')">
       <span class="alert">{{ deviceInfos.get('serialOKO').errors.invalidFormat.message}}</span> 
</div>
            </mat-form-field>


    <mat-form-field *ngIf= "deviceSelected" fxFlex="auto">
              <mat-label>Serial</mat-label>
              <input formControlName="serial" matInput>
              <div *ngIf="deviceInfos.controls.serial.hasError('invalidFormat')">
       <span class="alert">{{ deviceInfos.get('serial').errors.invalidFormat.message}}</span> 
</div>
            </mat-form-field>
            
            </div>

            <div class="actions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
            <button (click)="stepper.reset()" [disabled]="deviceInfos.pristine" color="primary" mat-button
                    type="button">RESET
            </button>

            <button (click)="getHardwareCheckInfosTwo(deviceInfos.get('serial').value, deviceInfos.get('serialOKO').value)" 
            *ngIf= "deviceSelected === 'AIUT GSM'" color="primary" 
            [disabled]="deviceInfos.pristine" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>NEXT
            </button>

            <button  (click)="getHardwareCheckInfosOne(deviceInfos.get('serial').value)"
            *ngIf= "deviceSelected !== 'AIUT GSM'" color="primary" 
            [disabled]="deviceInfos.pristine" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>NEXT
            </button>
          </div>

          </form>
      </mat-step>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What exactly does it mean by "_The problem is that data came after the step is initialize_"? Do you mean that some data aren't shown in the second step and is only rendered when you go back to step 1 and move again to step 2? Which variable is that exactly? `serial_number`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, is exactly that. The variable in question is serial_number but I would like to show others. The goal is to create a report of these variables.

Comment: Ignoring the nested subscription and a huge list of local variables (subjective) I don't see anything to stop the template from the rendering the value first time. You might have to show more information. Like how and when is the `getHardwareCheckInfosOne()` function triggered.

Comment: yes of course. I edit my post immediatly to show more informations